# bootstrap 3, Add a white close button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a white close button.
I've seen : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-close but how to have a white button instead of black ?

If I add "icon-white" in the class property it does not work...

For example :

```
 <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(newDelivery.transactions, $index)" class="close icon-white" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know : Add "white" class to the button, not "icon-white".

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="your call event">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```